# Buffer Strategy IllegalStateException

Tags: java, swing, bufferstrategy

I know this has been asked before but I still can't get it to work.

```
public class GUI extends JFrame implements Runnable{

    public static JPanel contentPane;
    public static Graphics2D graphics;
    public static BufferStrategy bufferStrategy;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    GUI frame = new GUI();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                    frame.setResizable(false);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public GUI() {
        setResizable(false);
        setTitle("Tower Defense Game");
        setIgnoreRepaint(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);


    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        createBufferStrategy(2);
        bufferStrategy = getBufferStrategy();
        graphics = (Graphics2D) bufferStrategy.getDrawGraphics();

        for(int infiniteVar = 0; infiniteVar == -1; infiniteVar++){

            graphics.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            graphics.drawLine(100, 100, (int) (Math.random() * ((200-50) + 1) + 50), (int) (Math.random() * ((200-50) + 1) + 50));

            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            infiniteVar = 0;
        }
    }
}
public class Initialize {

public static void main(String[] args){

    GUI.main(args);

    GUI objGUI = new GUI();
    Thread threadGUI = new Thread(objGUI);
    threadGUI.start();
}
}
```

I get `Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Component must have a valid peer on the line` where I try to make the buffer strategy. I think I'm supposed to make the frame first, but I do call that before I make the thread that makes the buffer strategy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, your problem starts here...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                GUI frame = new GUI();
                frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.setResizable(false);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

and is exasperated here...

```
public class Initialize {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        GUI.main(args);

        GUI objGUI = new GUI();
        Thread threadGUI = new Thread(objGUI);
        threadGUI.start();
    }
}
```

Basically, what is happening, the `GUI.main` method is creating a new instance of the `GUI`, which gets shown on the screen, then you create ANOTHER instance of GUI...

```
GUI objGUI = new GUI();
Thread threadGUI = new Thread(objGUI);
threadGUI.start();
```

to which you try and use to create the `BufferStrategy` with, but this instance is not visible on the screen (displayable, or attached to a native peer), hence your problem...

Instead, get rid of the `main` method in the `GUI`, it's not really doing any favors for you and apply it's logic in the `Initialize`

```
GUI frame = new GUI();
// Better idea to do this before you make the frame visible
// as it can change the frame borders and cause some issues
frame.setResizable(false); 
frame.setVisible(true);

Thread thread = new Thread(frame);
thread.start();
```

You can also add a check in your `run` method to wait till the `JFrame` becomes displayable...

```
@Override
public void run() {

    while (!isDisplayable()) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        }
    }
    //...
```

You should also read the JavaDocs on [`BufferStrategy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferStrategy.html) to better understand how to manage them...

Comment: Okay thanks, now the window actually pops up. But it doesn't draw the line. This is what I have for the loop:

for loop(shortened to fit)
   
   graphics = (Graphics2D) bufferStrategy.getDrawGraphics();
   
   graphics.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
   graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
   graphics.drawLine(100, 100, (int) (Math.random() * ((200-50) + 1) + 50), (int) (Math.random() * ((200-50) + 1) + 50));
   
   graphics.dispose();
   bufferStrategy.show();
   
   try {
    Thread.sleep(10);
   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
   
   infiniteVar = 0;
  }

Comment: I'm thinking, the `JRootPane` is blocking what is been painted to the frame.  Consider using a `java.awt.Canvas` to render to and add this to your frame